# In .NET 7 Publishing Web API To Local machine No HTTPS Endpoint

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-7.0

When I run my api from visual studio I get:

```
Now listening on: https://localhost:5000
```

I can make successful Postman requests using

```
https://localhost:5000/api/okya
```

When I publish my app to the local machine I get

```
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
```

From postman I can only make successful requests on

```
http://localhost:5000/api/okya
```

But NOT:

```
https://localhost:5000/api/okya
```

I get this console message:

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
      Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
```

I had a read of this article about publishing to local machine:
Enforcing https by Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio%2Clinux-ubuntu

And I added this to the program:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
{
    options.RedirectStatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect;
    options.HttpsPort = 5001;
});
```

Now in my console I have

```
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
```

BUT I can't make any http or https request from Postman

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:5001
```

Comment: Well I just made a new web api project and published it and I can not make https requests to the endpoint. I only have  Now listening on: http://localhost:5000

Comment: How about this `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`

Comment: Yes I have tried that to no avail.